# Blackberry SOAP Webservice

Tags: web-services, soap, blackberry

What is way to connect to SOAP based web service from Blackberry Application. Every one is using KSoap Library. Is there no native support in Blackeberry SDK to connect to webservice.?

Comment: There does appear to be built-in support as of OS 6.0: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/parser/soap/SOAPMessageProcessor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used HttpConnecttion to solve the problem I had.

Comment: Hi Krishnan, I am newby on Blackberry. I would greatly appriciate if you help me that how to access .net web services using HttpConnection?

Answer (score 2):

User JSR 172 webservices.  See NetBeans / Java ME IDE/SDK docs for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ksoap2 for blackberry application development when i am trying to send request through Soap then requestDump contains the value as

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><DownloadRetailerMobileApp xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/WSDL/Request.xsd" id="o0" c:root="1"><RetailerMSISDN>09886069494</RetailerMSISDN><RequestType>retailerowner</RequestType></DownloadRetailerMobileApp></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

and the responseDump what i am getting is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode xmlns="">SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring xmlns="">RuntimeError: Internal Server Error</faultstring><faultactor xmlns=""/></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and then it through an exception is

```
org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullParserException: expected:END_TAG{http://schemeas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop/}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Java Sun Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/download.html) to generate method stubs from your webservice using your webservices' wsdl file.

You can then call your webservice using the generated files, the syntax will be something like:

```
WebServiceSoap_Stub stub = new WebServiceSoap_Stub();
String result = stub.webMethod(param1, param2);
```

Comment: Hi Fermin,

I did not try this option, instead used HttpConnecttion available as part of Java. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Fermin, I have tryed `http` to access `.net web service` & got esponse in `xml formate`. Do you have any idea that how to get desired value/info from this xml? & moreover How this Stub classes work, i would greatly appriciate if you can provide me any code snippet or pointer that guide me step by step to how to access web service using wsdl & stub (as you have mentioed above).

Comment: @RupeshYadav, it's been a few years since I was doing this. The WirlessToolkit generates stub classes depending on the wsdl, these are just helper classes for web service methods. Calling the stub method calls the web service method and returns the result, just like a regular method call. If your call returns XML then you will need to write a parsing routine or use a parsing library to get your value from the XML.